# Static header and footer in Express JS

Tags: node.js, express, npm, handlebars.js

I am working with express js 4.14.0 and handlebars js 4.0.6. My view folder structure is like

```
view
   Layout.hbs
   Layout Folder
    - Main.hbs
  Partials Folder
    -Header.hbs
    -Footer.hbs
    -Page.hbs
 Index1.hbs
 Index2.hbs

app.engine( 'hbs', express_hbs( { 
  extname: 'hbs', 
  defaultLayout: 'main', 
  layoutsDir: __dirname + '/views/layouts/',
  partialsDir: __dirname + '/views/partials/'
} ) );
```

Main.hbs where the page starts to render initially is

```
<div class="bodyContent">
        <header>{{> header }}</header>
        <div class="container-fluid body-content">
            {{{body}}}
        </div>
        <footer>{{> footer }}</footer>  
    </div>
```

Initially Header, Footer and Page will get displayed through Index1.hbs page. When I am getting through to Index2.hbs page, Header and Footer is rendering again. It leads to flickering issue in header and footer when navigating between pages. How i can design Header and Footer like shared layout between the pages in express js using handlebars? How to overwrite the body content alone?

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be [turbolinks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/turbolinks) (a front-end solution available on npm). It'll replace the body of your current site with the `<body>` of the next page page and merges the `<header>`. Or you could try to write your own (maybe ajax) based solution that would replace the `body` of your current document with the `body` of the next page.

The flickering happens probably because you are navigating to a new site. Each template creates a new "real" html page, which includes the referenced partials.

Comment: Replacing the body content through ajax is a good idea. Already the body content  {{{body}}} is a partial view. How i can replace this with another partial view in ajax success?

Comment: Your client side can just view "full-pages" which are not partials - so it's not that easy. What's necessary is: Imagine a user is on page "Index1.html" and clicks a link which would redirect him to "index2.html", you have to load the "index2.html" using ajax (jquery etc.) and replace the body of your current "index.html" with the body of your "index2.html". I believe, it could be easier to integrate turbolinks, which covers your use case and is actively maintained.

Comment: @DhyaS did this answer help you?

Comment: @staar no idea of how to use this turbolink with handlebars. Is there any sample links available?